# api yandex maps on different pages of wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, yandex-maps

I have 4 pages in wordpress site where i need to inculde api yandex maps. So i created 4 scripts, which works. I included script tags in my footer:

```
        <!-- Yandex map scripts -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/bla" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/blabla" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/blablabla" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/blablablabla" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

All scripts have different ids for div blocks, different variable names. 
But when i put my divs inside 4 pages, only the first script is working, in this example i will see map only on the page that contains this script

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/bla" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Other pages will be blank.

In browser it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK9fO.png), so script is not working

If i load all 4 maps on 1 page it is working. But i want each map on certain page.

What should i do to get things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I guess we have to load yandex json every time.

`<!-- Yandex map scripts -->
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/wp-content/themes/bbbb" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/wp-content/themes/b" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/wp-content/themes/bbb" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/wp-content/themes/bb" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>`